# How do I stop the creation of a record using ActiveRecord before_create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I get ActiveRecord to accept all of the lines below. 
User1 saves both :name and :occupation to the db.
User2 doesn't need '12' stored in the db but needs to be evaluated based on the parameter then stored to the db with some default values.
User3 is a combination of both.

```
user1 = User.new(:name => "David", :occupation => "Artist")
user2 = User.new(12)
user3 = User.new(15, :name => "Mike", :occupation => "Programmer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'll answer based on my understanding...

Something like this should work in your `User` model:

```
before_create :set_defaults

def set_defaults
  return true unless default_case
  case default_case
    when 12
      self.name = 'John'
      self.occupation = 'Magician'
    when 15
      self.size = 'L'
    end
end
```

Then, when you create a new model:

```
User.new(:default_case => 15, :name => "Mike", :occupation => "Programmer")
```

Comment: What happens if set_defaults returns false? Does it cancel the create?

Comment: Nothing, unless I'm mistaken. But I like to return `true` if the method was successful. It stays consistent with `before_save` callbacks where `true` means success.

Comment: If I were to use User.new(15) instead of User.new(:default_case => 15) how may I access the parameter in the set_defaults function?

Comment: As far as I know, you won't be able to: constructors take a hash, a block, or `nil`. So unless your argument goes with a key you won't get access to it. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: Is it possible to cancel the creation of a record in before_save? If so then I'm thinking that I can remove the numeric parameter there.

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to pass parameters to an ActiveRecord calss on creation, they MUST be within a hash. Therefore you CANNOT have just a number parameter that doesn't correspond to a hash key. You can cancel model creation using validators (http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3?view=asciicast), but again : values MUST be passed in a hash.